# COALESCE() for blank (but not null) fields

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

I have two fields that I'm comparing with MySQL's function [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). For example, `COALESCE(Field1, Field2)`. The problem is, Field1 is sometimes blank but not null; since it's not null `COALESCE()` selects Field1, even though its blank. In that case, I need it to select Field2.

I know I can write a if-then-else (CASE) statement in the query to check for this, but is there a nice simple function like `COALESCE()` for blank-but-not-null fields?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(NULLIF(Field1,''),Field2)
```

NULLIF returns a NULL if Field1 is blank, while IFNULL returns Field1 if it's not blank or NULL and Field2 otherwise.

Comment: I could do the same, but with COALESCE correct? `COALESCE(NULLIF(Field1,''),Field2)` - is there a speed/processing load difference?

Comment: Interesting response about `COALESCE` vs `IFNULL` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747877/mysql-ifnull-vs-coalesce-which-is-faster

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm late to the party here, but there is a way to do this while still using COALESCE().  This would then work if your value was NULL or ''.

```
Select COALESCE(NULLIF(Field1,''), Field2)
```

Comment: See the comment on the selected answer :)

Answer (score 6):

You can  use a `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN Field1 <> '' THEN Field1 ELSE Field2 END
```

Comment: That's what I meant by if-then-else; I was looking for a cleaner, one-line solution

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE, for comparing both NULL and Blank.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Field1 IS NULL
            OR LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Field1))) < 1
            THEN Field2
        ELSE Field1
        END;
```

For comparing blank, do not use '', use LEN, LTRIM, RTRIM. Sometimes, blank may be with more than one spaces.