# Coalesce function for spaces/blanks

Tags: sql, db2

Is there something similar to the coalesce function for working with a CHAR column that may be blank?

For example, let's say I want to use `PREFERRED_NAME` if it exists, but use `FIRST_NAME` if it doesn't and the table I'm working with has data like this?

```
+-------------+----------------+ 
| FIRST_NAME  | PREFERRED_NAME | 
+-------------+----------------+ 
| JOHN        |                | 
| STEPHANIE   |                | 
| STEPHEN     | STEVE          | 
+-------------+----------------+
```

I was hoping to be able to write something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(PREFERRED_NAME,FIRST_NAME)
FROM   COMPANY.EMPLOYEES
```

... but it looks like `COALESCE` only works for `NULL` since for the data above my results look like this:

```
+---------+
| Column1 |
+---------+
|         |
|         |
| STEVE   |
+---------+
```

---

I found a potential solution in a [question for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13235847/945456) that looks like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(PREFERRED_NAME,''),FIRST_NAME)
```

Is using `NULLIF` or writing a `CASE` statement the best solution at this point? I was hoping for a single function that'd do it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(E.PREFERRED_NAME), ''), E.FIRST_NAME)
FROM COMPANY.EMPLOYEES E
```

Comment: The TRIM isn't really needed, DB2 will [pad the shorter side with spaces for comparison](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_stringcomparisionsintro.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a CASE statement:

```
case when length(trim(preferred_name)) > 0 
     then preferred_name 
     else first_name 
     end
```

You could certainly use this logic (or the `COALESCE(NULLIF(...))` logic in a user-defined function (UDF) that would allow you to "use a single function."

A better solution would be to make the `PREFERRED_NAME` column nullable, and avoid having 0-length values, but this is likely a more complicated solution.

Comment: I completely agree on the `PREFERRED_NAME` being nullable, unfortunately I don't have control over the schema so it is what it is.

Comment: For those interested in the future, here's some documentation on ["Creating a user-defined function"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_defineudf.html).

Comment: This wouldn't work if your name fields are defined as CHAR (since those are padded with spaces on the end).

Comment: @bhamby Wow, not sure what I was thinking there.  Corrected answer, thanks :-)