# If a select query return empty result, run another select query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 select statements.

```
1- select sm.id, IFNULL(sm.unit_price,0) as unit_price       
   from crm_stock_manager sm
   left join crm_purchase_order_items poi on poi.id = sm.purchase_order_item_id and  poi.is_del = 0
   left join crm_products p on poi.product_id = p.id and p.is_del = 0
   where sm.is_del = 0 and IFNULL(sm.unit_price, '') != '' and p.id = 253 order by sm.created_on;

2- select 0 as id ,price as unit_price from crm_products where id = 253  and is_del=0;
```

If 1st select statement return an empty result, then i want to run 2nd select statement.

Please help me.

Comment: Just perform 2 separated queries, one after another

Comment: Is there any possible ways to do this on mysql ?

Comment: is there any reason to do that in mysql?

Comment: Does this mean that you need to select crm_products.price if srm_stock_manager.unit_price is NULL?

Comment: Noop. if crm_stock_manager table contains any data i need to take the records from that table. other wise it will take from crm_products table.

Comment: @thing guy: time consumption from what perspective? Why do you think 1 monstruous query is faster than 2 trivial?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to work from a quick test I just did and avoids the need to check for the existence of x=1 twice.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM mytable
WHERE x = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 
FOUND_ROWS() = 0 AND x = 2;
```

Another way is Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT column1 FROM t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2);
```

Comment: Has the behavior of FOUND_ROWS() across SELECTs in the same UNION query changed? I'm seeing this method working for MySQL 5.1.61 but not for 5.6.15. In the latter case, FOUND_ROWS() in the second SELECT seems to return for the previous query instead of for the previous SELECT. Am I missing something?

Comment: Their is great difficulty between union and found rows but it depends on need and table schema

Comment: the not exists is a nice solution

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select `crm_products.price` if `srm_stock_manager.unit_price` is NULL, you can use `COALESCE` and you need not 2 queries. You can change your first part of `SELECT` statement as follows and other part as necessary to get the result required.

```
SELECT sm.id, COALESCE(sm.unit_price, p.price) unit_price FROM...
```

This returns `p.price` value if `sm.unit_price` is NULL.

Further, refer mysql [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Comment: `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747877/mysql-ifnull-vs-coalesce-which-is-faster).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
$query1 = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY");
$row_count = mysql_num_rows($query1);
if($row_count==0) {
 $query1 = mysql_query("Your Second Query");
}
```

Remember to not use `mysql_*` functions as they are depreciated.

Hope This Helps