# Mysql Query issue using between

Tags: mysql

I am trying to track inventory based only on install and removal dates and report what is installed at any given day. Records that are still installed, do not have a removal date. So I am trying to set the removal date to `Date(now())`. But when I add between `install_date` and `removal_date` it only finds records with both dates.

I have an inventory table which contains `name`, `install_date` and `removal_date` and i have a `master_date` table which contains all dates from 2012-01-01 to 2014-12-31

```
Select inventory.name, 
       inventory.install_date, 
       IFNULL(inventory.removal_date,DATE(NOW())), 
       master_date.date 
FROM inventory, master_date 
WHERE master_date.date BETWEEN inventory.install_date 
                       AND inventory.removal_date
```

If I remove the between clause, it sets `removal_date` to NOW, but continues to include records where the `removal_date` is prior to NOW. With the where clause, it only returns records where `removal_date` is not null but the date field is correct.

How can I use NOW in place of a NULL `removal_date` and return the correct records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COALESCE() which returns the first non-null value in the supplied parameters.

You can do:

```
BETWEEN inventory.install_date AND COALESCE(inventory.removal_date, DATE(NOW())
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: According to this SO answer, it seems that COALESCE() is standard while IFNULL() is not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747877/mysql-ifnull-vs-coalesce-which-is-faster

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, by saying:

```
Select IFNULL(inventory.removal_date,DATE(NOW()))
```

You're returning a new field.

Try:

```
Select inventory.name, 
       inventory.install_date, 
       IFNULL(inventory.removal_date,DATE(NOW())), 
       master_date.date 
FROM inventory, master_date 
WHERE master_date.date BETWEEN inventory.install_date 
                       AND IFNULL(inventory.removal_date,DATE(NOW()))
```