# Is it possible to make that instead of NULL will be displayed 0?

Tags: mysql

Code:

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as count, 
  sum(Status = 'test1') as count_test1, 
  sum(Status = 'test2') as count_test2
FROM Table
WHERE Type = 'test'
```

in result i see:

```
count   count_test1   count_test2
  0       NULL           NULL
```

***Tell me please is it possible to make that instead of NULL will be displayed 0?***

*P.S.: That results was:*

```
count   count_test1   count_test2
  0       0               0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(sum(Status = 'test1'), 0)
```

or `IFNULL`

```
IFNULL(sum(Status = 'test1'), 0)
```

Comment: use `COALESCE(sum(Status = 'test1'), 0) as count_test1`   ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as count, 
      IFNULL(sum(Status = 'test1'), 0) as count_test1, 
      IFNULL(sum(Status = 'test2'), 0) as count_test2
FROM Table
WHERE Type = 'test'
```

Comment: I feel IFNULL to be more specific in this case. Additional reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747877/mysql-ifnull-vs-coalesce-which-is-faster

Comment: @VincentTan I believe it is very slightly quicker but I do have to admit not as portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/comparison-operators.html?iframe=true&width=100%&he..) function which take an array and return the first element not null

```
SELECT 
  count(*) as count, 
  COALESCE(sum(Status = 'test1'), 0) as count_test1, 
  COALESCE(sum(Status = 'test2'), 0) as count_test2
FROM Table
WHERE Type = 'test'
```