# SQL Error When Selecting Max Value from Multiple Columns in Tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table full of individual bowling scores (table: bowlers) for a charity bowling tournament. I'm trying to pull out the top individual scores for males and females over a possible 3 games of bowling, link them up with the team name from a different table (table: teams), and then order the top scores in descending order.

I'm starting with the male scores and have an SQL query that I think should work to select the top score for each person across their possible three games, then order all of the records in descending order. I based it off of the answer I found to a similar question on Stack Overflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871572

Here's my query:

```
$topmalebowler = "SELECT bowlers.bowler_name, teams.team_name, 
(SELECT MAX(v) FROM (VALUES (bowlers.game_1_score), 
(bowlers.game_2_score), (bowlers.game_3_score)) AS value(v)) 
as TopScore FROM bowlers INNER JOIN teams ON 
bowlers.team_id=teams.team_id WHERE bowlers.sex = 'M' 
ORDER BY 'TopScore' DESC";
```

I keep getting an error with it, though.

> *"Error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'VALUES (bowlers.game_1_score), (bowlers.game_2_score),
>   (bowlers.g' at line..."*

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make this code tie the room together?

Note: MySQL 5.5

Comment: I'm sure you copied one of these down wrong, but your code is referencing the `bowlers` table and your error is referencing the `bowlers_2016` table.

Comment: You're right...fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: If you're using MySQL then you should look at the second most upvoted answer on the question you linked. The syntax you're using only works in Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: Thank you, Terminus! I tried the GREATEST function and it did work. Problem solved. If anyone has an idea for why this query didn't work, though, I am curious what I was missing.

Comment: Check that...problem not quite solved. GREATEST seems to ignore rows with null values in any of the columns it looks at.

Comment: @TMax I see your questions were answered; good! In case you haven't already, don't forget to up vote the answers that helped in the question you linked :) Also, for your reading pleasure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747877/mysql-ifnull-vs-coalesce-which-is-faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you originally posted was written for T-SQL and SQL Server, the Microsoft implementations of SQL. You are running MySQL, which sometimes has different syntax. As Terminus pointed out, the thing to use for MySQL is the `GREATEST` function.

To avoid skipping rows with at least one NULL game score, you would structure the query like this:

```
SELECT bowlers.bowler_name, teams.team_name,
GREATEST(
    IFNULL(bowlers.game_1_score, 0),
    IFNULL(bowlers.game_2_score, 0),
    IFNULL(bowlers.game_3_score, 0)) AS TopScore
FROM bowlers
INNER JOIN teams ON bowlers.team_id=teams.team_id
WHERE bowlers.sex = 'M' 
ORDER BY 'TopScore' DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, tschwab. After experimenting with it a bit more, though, I've discovered that GREATEST doesn't seem to take into account rows with null values. For example, a bowler with a high score, but a value of 'null' for game_3_score. Is there a way to account for those and still use the GREATEST function? That was one of the reasons why I was trying to make the "MAX" function work, since it seemed to allow for null values.

Comment: My apologies, that answer only works for two columns. I updated my answer.

Comment: That's it! Thank you, tschwab....I kept trying versions of your edits with no success, but this last one solved the problem. I very much appreciate your help with this!

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help.